# OpenCV drawing specific contours

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I have GUI elements that i want to detect, background colors are varying a lot and i am having problems detecting diamond shape contours.

Original image:

[image: Original image]

What i have so far:

[image: Input]

I get this image with a simple bgr to gray conversion, blurring then applying a gaussian adaptive threshold with this code:

```py
crop_img = img.copy()
crop_gray = cv2.cvtColor(crop_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.blur(crop_gray, (5, 5), 0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blurred, 255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 21, 4)
```

The result i want is to just locate the icon frames like this:

[image: expected]

I already tried different techniques using some combinations of morphological transformations but my lack of experience in image processing is giving me a hard time figuring this one out.

Edit: Added original image

Comment: Seems like the preprocessing chain can be improved. Can you post the original image?

Comment: Absolutely. [Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIEAv.png).

Comment: Instead of adaptive thresholding, I would recommend `cv2.inRange()` method to filter out the colors of diamond shaped objects in a specific range.

Comment: I definitely tried that too but since the icon luminosity and color can change, it's hard to find a reasonable color range to mask other than iterating through them.  @ZdaR If for example i wanted to mask the bottom icon's purple what range can you suggest? Thanks

Comment: Instead of masking the purple, you can try masking the black border around the diamond shapes. It is consistent across all the 4 diamonds. I tried with (0, 0, 0), (15, 15, 15) BGR range and it successfully detected the top 2 diamonds while partially detecting the bottom two , you can play with this color range a bit or can also use HSV color range instead of BGR

Comment: can you share another 1 or 2 more images that are different so we can see whats in common

Comment: Here you [go](https://lensdump.com/a/IDFjF). I'm starting to think that i should be looking into training a machine learning model for it but on the other side even a simple imperfect image processing solution that can precisely match one of them could work since i can predict the position of the rest, so far matching colors (purple,green,etc) results varies from really good to terrible. [examples](https://lensdump.com/a/IDUq3)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know these GUI elements are from Dead By Daylight(Game). Thus, I assume that you want to process the video feed from the game.

You can use consecutive frames and track the similarities between them. Since the background changes as the player or the in game objects move, the only part which does not change is the GUI elements. I wrote a pseudocode below which compares 2 frames and outputs a mask which shows the unchanged pixels.

```
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim
  
frame0 = video_feed.get_next_frame()
frame1 = video_feed.get_next_frame()

gray_frame0 = cv2.cvtColor(frame0, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray_frame1 = cv2.cvtColor(frame1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

(score, diff) = compare_ssim(gray_frame0, gray_frame1, full=True)

thresh = cv2.threshold(diff, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

Hope this kind of approach works for your application.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and sorry for the late response. I do not actually have a video feed, I'm trying to process single images individually. I ended up using feature matching which is not ideal processing time wise but works alright for the time being.